# Multiple protractor suites not running on chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I have multiple suites in protractor which i want to test and run.It runs fine on Mozilla Firefox but only the first suite runs while using Google chrome(Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)

```
 suites: {
         lawfirm: [
            '../Test_Suites/Lawfirm/signUp_spec.js',
            '../Test_Suites/Lawfirm/login_spec.js',


        ],

         beneficiary :  [
           '../Test_Suites/Beneficiary/loginBeneficiary_spec.js',


          ]

    },
```

Protractor Version : 3.3.0

Comment: check the spec path or renaming issues

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make suites an array, just use `*` to denote all files under a certain directory.

```
suites: {
    lawfirm: '../Test_Suites/Lawfirm/*.spec.js'
}
```

Then run as you would normally:

```
protractor conf.js --suite lawfirm
```

Comment: If i use **lawfirm: '../Test_Suites/Lawfirm/*.spec.js'**  then How can maintain the sequence of spec files under Lawfirm suites ?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a good idea to make your tests independent at the file level.  They should be able to run without another test file running.  Anyway, the tests should execute in alphabetical/hierarchal order, but I don't think this is guaranteed and would not be easy to keep up in practice

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put an array. Just a comma separated list (no spaces after the comma either)

suites:{
     suite1:'....','....',
     suite2:'...','....'
}

Here is where you can find more information on the protractor config setup:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js

Comment: If i use **lawfirm: '../Test_Suites/Lawfirm/*.spec.js'**  then How can maintain the sequence of spec files under Lawfirm suites ?

Comment: I think by default it will use alpha order of the tests matching, but if u want to force the order you can list them out, comma separated(no space before comma) and it will run the tests in the order you list